# Create an instance of the class in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

Сreate an instance of the class in aspx. Created the project. Created a class. Created a page. And I want to create an instance of the class.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PartyInvites.Default" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xh`enter code here`tml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="PartyStyles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            MyClass cl = new MyClass();
        %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

http://pixs.ru/showimage/1png_9106819_14067314.png

Does not work:
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 10: <body>
Line 11:     <%
Line 12:         MyClass cl = new MyClass();
Line 13:     %>
Line 14:
```

Comment: Create the the instance of the MyClass class in the code behind of the aspx page.

Comment: This class has a method. How do I display the result in the aspx?

Comment: You can create in your aspx page a control. For example: <form runat="server">
<asp:Literal ID="Foo" runat="server" />
</form>. Than from the code behind you can say: Foo.Text = cl.method(); Literal is for string value. I suggest you to have a look for other webforms controls if you want to display something else

Comment: You must add the using for the namespace of the class. Sometimes you can right click it and select ‘Resolve`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Silvermind says in their comment, you're missing the namespace.

You have two obvious choices (there might be others I'm not aware of), either use it directly...

```
<%
  PartyInvites.MyClass cl = new PartyInvites.MyClass();
%>
```

(Note, this can also be shorted to just `var cl = new PartyInvites.MyClass();`)

Or include the namespace at the top of your page using

```
<%@ Import Namespace="PartyInvites" %>
```

Comment: `PartyInvites.MyClass cl = new PartyInvites.MyClass();`

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MyClass' does not exist in the namespace 'PartyInvites' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

`Source Error:
Line 12: <%  `
`Line 13:     PartyInvites.MyClass cl = new PartyInvites.MyClass();`
`Line 14:     //Response.Write(myVar.ToString());`
`Line 15:       %>`

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, declare a global variable in class level, such as:

```
protected int myVar;
```

Then, in the page_load() (for instance), you can do this:

```
MyClass cl = new MyClass();
myVar = cl.foo();
```

Now, on your ASP.Net page:

```
<%= myVar %>
```